# python's **kwargs efficiency

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, avro, keyword-argument

Is it fine to build python3 flow like this?

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    kwargs['kw'] = 1
    return bar(**kwargs, wk=2)
def bar(**kwargs):
    process(1,2,'sss',**kwargs)
    for i in kwargs:
        print(i)
...etc...
```

Is kwargs going to single mutable object (`dict`) and only it's reference will be pass down the flow or will i be unpacked and created over and over?

More precise question. If i do this:

```
def a(**kwargs):
    return b(**kwargs)
def b(**kwargs):
    return c(**kwargs)
...
def z(**kwargs):
    print(**kwargs)
```

will there only be 1 dict at a time? And if so will there be new object created with each call?
or will i stack them?

The actual case is that I am one of sub services that communicates with AVRO. So I have a package that turns that binary into a `dict`, then i need to do something and create a new AVRO.

Some fields are not present in new schema, some are added, some are just passing without touching them.

So i just took that first dict, pass it over and over add more and more data then at the end i have another schema and avro package can take such huge dict and serialize only what is defined in the schema.

Is that approach ok?

Comment: Generally, this approach goes against everything I understand about programming, but if all you want to do is mutate this dict, I don't really see why not...

Comment: No i want to create a good code. The problem was that i wanted minimize the work that needs to be done when schema changes, and that the code itself didn't look strongly related to the schema. How would u approach this?

Comment: if you want to do this, why don't you just pass a dict and make the argument explicit?

Comment: because at the top of the chain is something that passes some arguments by kwargs i thought i could use this dict instead making a new one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A new dictionary is built for each `**kwargs` parameter in each function. That's because the *call* `**kwargs` syntax is distinct from the syntax in a function signature

- Using `**kwargs` in call causes a dictionary to be unpacked into separate keyword arguments.
- Using `**kwargs` as a catch-all parameter causes a dictionary to be *produced* from keyword arguments being passed in.

Even if this wasn't the case, Python can't optimise by sharing the dictionary. Function `foo()` calling `bar()` would have to handle the possibility that a dictionary `kwargs` passed into a call could be mutated.

So, no, using `**kwargs` in a series of connected functions is not going to give you more efficiency.

A quick demo to show that the dictionaries passed into a series of functions are distinct:

```
>>> def a(**kwargs):
...     print('a', id(kwargs))
...     b(**kwargs)
...
>>> def b(**kwargs):
...     print('b', id(kwargs))
...
>>> a(foo='bar')
a 4556474552
b 4557517304
```

If the dictionaries were shared, their `id()` value would also be the same.

If you want to pass along shared state between functions, do so explicitly. Pass the dictionary along directly, for example:

```
def foo(**state):
    state['kw'] = 1
    state['wk'] = 2
    return bar(state)  # kwargs passed in as a single argument

def bar(state):
    # etc.
```

Comment: That's what i was afraid of, If i wrap this all in a class, make a field with a dict and modify it everywhere i get what i want right?

Comment: @Kazz: yes, you can always pass along a plain dictionary or a custom mutable object.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I really like Martijn's answer. To answer your question the way I believe you intended it, you need to skip the `**` as Martijn said;

```
def a(some_dict):
    # do some operations on this dict
    b(some_dict)

def b(some_dict):
    # do some more operations on this dict
    c(some_dict)

def c(some_dict):
    # you know how this goes by know, don't you?

# Careful thing to note here: you do not need to reassign here,
# since each function are dealing with a reference to the same
# original object, there is no need to pass it back when we are
# done.

a(some_dict)
```

To add further, this is quite common in what I believe to be a factory pattern;

```
class CookLasagna:
    def __init__(self, lasagna=None):
        self.lasagna = lasagna
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        self.preheat_oven()
        self.cook_minced_meat()
        self.soak_pasta()
        self.layer()

    def preheat_oven(self):
        # preheat the oven with lasagna object reference

    def cook_minced_meat(self):
        # cook minced meat with lasagna object reference

    def soak_pasta(self):
        # soak pasta with lasagna object reference

    def layer(self):
        # layer with lasagna object reference
```

Comment: lol, exactly what i need. I need to read more about code patterns

Answer (score -1):

It's quite easy to find out what happens directly:

```
def a(**kwargs):
    b(**kwargs)
    print(kwargs)  # prints {'x': 1}, not {'x': 1, 'y': 2}

def b(**kwargs):
    kwargs['y'] = 2

a(x=1)
```

So there is a new dict each time.

Comment: That's not what i asked about

Comment: you asked "will there only be 1 dict at a time?"

Comment: @Kazz could you explain why not? Perhaps I wasn't clear. If there was a single dict being passed around, then `a` would print out `{'x': 1, 'y': 2}`.

Comment: i was talking about chaining calls like `a(b(c(d(..))))`. Of course in your code when `b` is called `a` is not finished so it goes to the stack to be returned to it later.

Comment: ok, i guess i wasn't clear. I meant will there be 20 dicts after 20 calls ?

Comment: You definitely weren't talking about `a(b(c(d(..))))`, that has no relation to anything mentioned anywhere on this page.

`**kwargs` will create a new dict for each call. When the call finishes the dict will be garbage collected, so no, there will not be 20 dicts *after* 20 calls, but 20 dicts will be created.

I don't fully understand your situation but if you're worried about the performance cost of creating a new dict every time, you probably shouldn't be.

Comment: Yes i know that `a(b(c(d(..))))` will make a mess, i was wondering if it's same with `def a(**kwargs): return b(**kwargs)`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by it will make a mess. Nothing will make a mess: if you can't find any incorrect behaviour or differences in performance, you're fine. Call and define the functions however makes you happy.